# Iterating over the map and calling another method

Tags: java, dictionary

I am getting an map as shown below inside a method

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result1 =jmxService.generateMabc(p1, p2,p3,p4);
```

now the map result 1 will consists oif key value pair  as usal
now i want to iterate over the map one by one , fetch the value of the map
that is both key and value which will be of type integer and convert them into string
and store the string two string variables like shown below

string j = will store the key
string t = will store the value

amd then pass these two parameters to another method call which wil take string
j and string t as parameter once they pass i want j and t to be null so that in next iteration the same process and can be continued till the time map has value c an you please advise how to achieve this, what I have tried is..

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result1.entrySet())
            {

            String j, t;
               j=entry.getKey();
               t= entry.getValue();

abc .callanothermethod(string p1,stringp2, stringj, string t)
j=null;
t=null;
   }
```

please advise what will be the correct appoach to obtain the same.

Answer (score 0):

An Integer is not a String. So `j = entry.getKey()` doesn't make sense.

You need to transform the Integer into a String (by calling `toString()` for example):

```
j = entry.getKey().toString();
```

You really need to learn to

- read the error messages from the compiler, which tell you waht is wrong and where
- read the javadoc of the classes you're using, to understand what you can do with them.

Comment: thanks I have done that..String t, k;for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result1.entrySet())
{t= entry.getKey().toString() ;k=entry.getValue().toString();abc .callanothermethod(string p1,stringp2, stringj, string t)
}

Comment: Can you please advise also I have declared the string parameters outside the for loop is it the correct way.

Comment: No. You should generally reduce the scope of your variables as much as possible. If they're only used inside the loop, there's no reason to declare them outside. What you should do, though, is giving them meaningful names. `j` and `t` are awful names.